# Difference between linux curl and python requests, why GET request has different result?

Tags: python, curl, request

Why next two methods of obtaining authentication token are not equivalent?
First one is using `curl` in terminal:

```
curl -X POST "http://myurl.com" -d "grant_type=password&username=me&password=mypass&client_secret=123&client_id=456"
```

This request successfully returns the token.
If I use requests library for python:

```
import requests   
url = 'http://myurl.com'                                                              

query_args = { "grant_type":"password",
               "username":'me',
               "password":'mypass',
               "client_secret":'123',
               'client_id':'456'}
r = requests.get(url, data=query_args)
```

the result I get is `r.status_code` is `404`, so I cannot get the token.
Why the first method works and the second does not?

Also, how to make the second approach work?

Thank you!

Comment: url is the same as in the curl request. I have changed all names and credentials, but I double checked that url and credentials coincide in both approaches.

Comment: why are you calling data=query_args and not params=query_args

Comment: also does print(r.url) show what you expect?

Comment: @AcyclicTau because I use `-d` in curl, which means 'data'.

Comment: print(r.url) returns string `url` in python code

Comment: Looks like curl -d uses a POST request, but the python snippet uses GET.

Comment: @monkey OMG, that is the reason, how I missed it, so obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the curl `-d` flag send data as post data, from the man page:

> ```
>    -d/--data <data>
> ```
>
> (HTTP)  Sends  the  specified  data  in  a POST request to
>   the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl  to  pass  the  data  to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F/--form.

So you should be using `request.post`. You will also possibly want to use the params attribute not the data one, see the following example:

```
>>> data = {'test':'12345'}
>>> url = 'http://myurl.com'
>>> r = requests.post(url,params=data)
>>> print r.url
http://myurl.com/?test=12345
>>> r = requests.post(url,data=data)
>>> print r.url
http://myurl.com/
>>>
```